# How to parse and build an URL query string with multiple value parameters in R

Tags: r, url, query-string, httr

Is there a straightforward way to parse and build URL query string with multiple value parameters in R ?

I would expect something like

```
myqueryString <- parse_url("http://www.mysite.com/?a=1&a=2&b=val")$query
myqueryString
  $a
  [1] 1 2
  $b
  [1] "val"
```

and

```
urlElements <- list(scheme="http",path="www.mysite.com/",query=list(a=c(1,2),b="val"))
setattr(urlElements,"class","url")
build_url(urlElements)
  [1] "http://www.mysite.com/?a=1&a=2&b=val"
```

However `httr` gives

```
parse_url("http://www.mysite.com/?a=1&a=2&b=val")$query
 $a
 [1] "1"

 $a
 [1] "2"

 $b
 [1] "val"
```

and

```
builtURL <- build_url(urlElements)
builtURL
   [1] "http:///www.mysite.com/?a=c%281%2C%202%29&b=val"
```

This latest URL can be reprocessed

```
parse_url(builtURL)$query
 $a
 [1] "c(1, 2)"

 $b
 [1] "val"
```

I understand that I can use `parse()` + `eval()` to get `a` back but it looks fairly unsafe to eval code that can be freely dumped to an URL. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: You could 'collapse' the result of `parse_url` to what you expect it to. `x <- list(a = "1", a = "2", b = "val"); lapply(split(x, as.factor(names(x))), function(y) do.call("c", y))
`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if these work to convert between those two argument list formats:

```
mergeUrlArgs <- function(x) sapply(unique(names(x)), function(z) unlist(x[names(x) == z], use.names=FALSE), simplify=FALSE)

expandUrlArgs <- function(x) structure(do.call(c, lapply(x, function(z) as.list(z))), names=rep(names(x), sapply(x, length)))
```